# Getting Unicode ODBC Teradata Drivers to Work on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, unicode, stata, teradata, unixodbc

I am trying to configure the Unicode version of Teradata 15.10 ODBC drivers to work on an Ubuntu server. I need to use unixODBC because that is required by my statistics package Stata, which does not support Unicode drivers with iODBC on Linux. I installed the TD drivers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636832/accessing-teradata-database-using-stata-in-linux-and-odbc).

Here's some information about my setup:

```
$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/dmasterov/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8

$ odbcinst -q -d
[ODBC DRIVERS]
[Teradata]

$ odbcinst -q -s
[ODBC]
[mozart]

$ cat ~/.odbc.ini
[ODBC]
InstallDir=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64
Trace=0
TraceDll=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/odbctrac.so
TraceFile=~/trace.log
TraceAutoStop=0

[ODBC Data Sources]
mozart=tdata.so

[mozart]
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdata.so
Description=mozart
DBCName=VVVVVVVVVV
Username=YYYYYYYYY
Password=XXXXXXXXX
CharacterSet=UTF8

$ cat /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC DRIVERS]
Teradata=Installed

[Teradata]
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdata.so
APILevel=CORE
ConnectFunctions=YYY
DriverODBCVer=3.51
SQLLevel=1

$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib64

$ echo $ODBCINI
/home/dmasterov/.odbc.ini
```

I am able to use both `isql` and `tdxodbc64` without errors, except that all Unicode characters are missing in the displayed output, as if they are not there at all.

With the ANSI driver, everything works nicely (except the Unicode characters disappear):

```
. set odbcmgr unixodbc

. set odbcdriver ansi

. odbc list

Data Source Name                   Driver
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mozart                             tdata.so
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. odbc load, exec("SELECT XXXXXX;") dsn("mozart") lowercase clear
```

When I try using the Unicode driver in Stata, the DSN names are mangled and I get the following error when I try to load the data:

```
. set odbcdriver unicode

. odbc list

Data Source Name                   Driver
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
楶慶摬i⇩奙羱                       摴瑡⹡潳㘀앏畟Е
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. odbc load, exec("SELECT XXXXXX;") dsn("mozart") lowercase clear
The ODBC driver reported the following diagnostics
[DataDirect][ODBC lib] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
SQLSTATE=IM002
[DataDirect][ODBC lib] Invalid connection string attribute
SQLSTATE=01S00
r(682);
```

I am guessing that the DataDirect ODBC connector is getting involved somewhere in this process, and the Unicode characters are getting lost in translation.

How can I determine what exactly is going wrong? Is there anything that I can do to fix it? I also have a similar problems on my Mac laptop.

---

Edit #1: Output of `strace isql mozart 2>~/strace.log` [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rq2vlfhrf5ixxdn/strace.log?dl=0).

Comment: Will you be able to share the unixODBC trace?